VCL : How can I know what color is the border of a control?
I would like the cells of the first row of a StringGrid to have the same border as the outside of the StringGrid. But I can't find any property giving me the color used to draw the border. How am I supposed to get it ?
Note that I am using VSF styles.

Are you thinking about TStringGrid.FixedRows ?  See -> https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.FixedRows for more info.

Do you mean VCL styles?

I mean that the style are loaded from .vsf files. Not sure if there's an official name for that.

@EirikA. I'm drawing the stringgrid myself, but in essence yes.
